# how do I show that the set $\{x \in a : b \approx S_x \}$ is nonempty?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here's a proof of the theorem from Charles Pinter's A book of set theory:

[image]

It seems intuitive but **how do I show that the set $\{x \in a : b \approx S_x \}$ is nonempty?** (I don't see how. Since $b< a$, there is an injection $b\to a$. How do I use this to establish that there is an $x\in a$ such that $b\approx S_x$?)

Also when the author says well order $a$, he means that there is a well ordering relation $\preceq$ on $A$ and shouldn't he mean $\varphi (d) \preceq \varphi (b)$ instead of the already used symbol $\leqslant$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an injection $f:b\to a$. Let $F=f[b]\subseteq a$, and recursively define a (possibly partial) function $h$ from a subset of $a$ onto $F$ as follows: if $h\upharpoonright S_x$ has been defined for some $x\in a$, and $h[S_x]\subsetneqq F$, let $h(a)=\min(F\setminus h[S_x])$. Informally $h$ sends the least element of $a$ to the least element of $F$, the next smallest element of $a$ to the next smallest element of $F$, and so on. In the end either $\operatorname{dom}h=a$, or there is an $x\in a$ such that $\operatorname{dom}h=S_x$. If $\operatorname{dom}h=a$, then $h^{-1}\circ f$ would be a bijection from $b$ to $a$, which is impossible, since $b<a$, so $\operatorname{dom}h=S_x$ for some $x\in a$, and $S_x\approx b$.

There’s no real harm here in using the same symbol for both orders, since it’s easy enough to keep straight which set one is working in.